# Making the cover image responsive on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a cover photo on the front page of my website and it looks fine on desktop and scales with the browser size being changed, but looks absolutely horribly when opened on a mobile device.

Here's what I am using:

```
.first {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    position:relative; 
    background: url(../photo.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I also tried doing this:

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    /* Small screen, non-retina */
        .first { 
            background: url(../photo.jpg);
            width: 50%;
            height: 50%; }
    }

    @media only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 320px) {
        /* Small screen, retina */
        .first { 
            background: url(../photo.jpg);
            width: 50%;
            height: 50%; }    
        }
```

But that didn't work.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What does it look like? Could you post a link to the site or screenshot of the problem?

Comment: yes, sure! yudasina.com

Comment: I think the issue might be cause of the mobile *viewport* and the fact that you use the `fixed` property, which results in a wrongly positioned/sized bg image cause it *fixes* to the document-size, not the *viewport*.

Answer (score 2):

We have a unique class on the image, so set the image absolutely positioned, and set the width using a percentage directly in the CSS.

[image]
You are using same classes more than once.

```
.first {
    background: url("../lyuba_final.jpg") no-repeat fixed center center / cover rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

See your reptition below

[image]

Comment: if I do that the text from the section under the photo goes under it and the arrow is not positioned on the photo anymore :/

Comment: @yudasinal Clean your css code and everything will work fine.

Comment: ok, thanks! but at the same time, it didn't scale before I added those @media tags (which had the same .first class). but how can I make it occupy only half of the page on mobile instead of cover?

Comment: You should also check the aspect ratio of your images while scaling..See how we can maintain the image aspect ratios http://jsfiddle.net/Y8QC9/

Comment: sorry, I just wasn't online. I will definitely vote it up. And if you want me to, I have no problem accepting it, although it didn't actually solve my problem :/

Comment: @yudasinal there is an example which shows how to maintain the image aspect ratios and also few corrections on css classes were suggested.. what more help you need?

Comment: yes, it does indeed scale when you just reduce the browser's window. But if you open it on an actual mobile device - nothing scales, it just shows a zoomed in piece of the photo :(

Comment: @yudasinal Hi can you try this method which uses jquery.. See demo here.. http://jsfiddle.net/TRHc7/

Answer (score 0):

Define horrible? What happens?
What mobile devices?

if you target the html element it should scale well.

```
html { 
  background: url(../photo.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

On mobile devices the image will be most likely cropped.

Comment: good point. horrible - it just shows a really small part of the picture on horrible and it occupies the whole screen, whereas i want the full to be seen and occupy just half of the screen on mobile. I can't use it as an html attribute, as I have other background pics in the site

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    .first {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: url(9.jpg) no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%;
/*if you don't want to maintain aspect ratio of image and make it cover entire screen
 use: background-size: 100% 100%;
*/
    }  
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="first">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps..